# What type of element *is* an `<li>`?

Tags: html, html-lists

So I'm working on a script to check for valid HTML structure when I noticed something a little odd...

`<li>` does not seem to be listed as a block **or** inline element. Not W3C, not [Moz Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements), or even [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#kinds-of-content).

The same goes for `<dt>` and `<dd>`, they just disappear into limbo and give no definitive element type.

So my question is: **What *is* an `<li>` tag?** Block, inline, *both*?

While we're at it: **What is allowed *inside* of one of these ambiguous tags?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion probably arises because the terms "block" and "inline" have been applied to various different things.

**Collections of elements in the HTML DTDs**

`li` falls into neither group because it is only allowed as a child element of `ul` and `ol` rather then the many places that `%block` and `%inline` content is allowed.

**CSS display properties**

As well as elements which have those values for that property by default.

`li` elements have been `display: list-item` since CSS 1.

**Elements which trigger line breaks (and those which do not)**

These are very broad terms that aren't really useful in a technical sense.

---

HTML 5 has dropped the terms for the purposes of describing elements, and you should too.

> What is allowed inside of one of these ambiguous tags?

See [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element):

> **Content model**:
>   
> Flow content.

Flow content is defined as:

> - `a`
> - `abbr`
> - `address`
> - `area` (if it is a descendant of a `map` element)
> - `article`
> - `aside`
> - `audio`
> - `b`
> - `bdi`
> - `bdo`
> - `blockquote`
> - `br`
> - `button`
> - `canvas`
> - `cite`
> - `code`
> - `data`
> - `datalist`
> - `del`
> - `details`
> - `dfn`
> - `dialog`
> - `div`
> - `dl`
> - `em`
> - `embed`
> - `fieldset`
> - `figure`
> - `footer`
> - `form`
> - `h1`
> - `h2`
> - `h3`
> - `h4`
> - `h5`
> - `h6`
> - `header`
> - `hr`
> - `i`
> - `iframe`
> - `img`
> - `input`
> - `ins`
> - `kbd`
> - `keygen`
> - `label`
> - `main`
> - `map`
> - `mark`
> - `math`
> - `meter`
> - `nav`
> - `noscript`
> - `object`
> - `ol`
> - `output`
> - `p`
> - `pre`
> - `progress`
> - `q`
> - `ruby`
> - `s`
> - `samp`
> - `script`
> - `section`
> - `select`
> - `small`
> - `span`
> - `strong`
> - `style` (if the `scoped` attribute is present)
> - `sub`
> - `sup`
> - `svg`
> - `table`
> - `textarea`
> - `time`
> - `u`
> - `ul`
> - `var`
> - `video`
> - `wbr`
> - `text`

Comment: Even on that list, there is no mention of `li`, `dt`, nor `dl`. So the answer is that *it just is*? and according to "Otherwise, the list item has no defined list-related relationship to any other li element.", a list item can be by itself, without a parent list container, it just therefor has no associations to any other?

Comment: *Even on that list, there is no mention of *: `li` and `dt` aren't mentioned because it wouldn't make sense for them to be there. They must appear in `ul`/`ol` or `dl` elements respectively, you can't have them directly inside a list item. `dl` *does* appear in that list.

Comment: *So the answer is that it just is?*: Sort of. The answer is more "You are trying to use an HTML 4 shorthand for something it isn't intended for, and that doesn't make sense."

Comment: *the list item has no defined list-related relationship to any other li element* — There is no direct relationship between list items. They have to be members of a list, and they usually have other list items as siblings.

Comment: er sorry, meant `dd`. An `li` *will* display outside of a list container, but you're saying that would be improper? (I would agree, but that statement seems to contradict)

Comment: *a list item can be by itself, without a parent list container* — No. You were asking about what is allowed inside a list item, not what its parent elements might be. That is covered on the paragraph immediately before the part of the list specification that I quoted: Contexts in which this element can be used:
Inside ol elements.
Inside ul elements.

Comment: So then what *is* allowed inside of an `li`? Anything but headers? Any content flow item?

Comment: *An li will display outside of a list container, but you're saying that would be improper?* — Yes, browsers perform a lot of error recover to handle mistakes by HTML authors.

Comment: @kcdwayne — I quoted the specification in the second half of this answer, and no, that list includes headings, and the header element and doesn't include many other things.

Comment: Which is about as straightforward as a form from the DMV. What I gather is: you can treat it like a block, but it would probably be more correct to treat it as an inline (as in the case of headings). I have never known a page to break over such elements inside of it, but it looks like about anything goes, it should just be approached with a "less is more" approach for the sake of clean markup.

Comment: It's extremely straightforward! With only two simple provisos, it's a simple list of acceptable elements!

Comment: *What I gather is: you can treat it like a block, but it would probably be more correct to treat it as an inline (as in the case of headings).* — See the first half of the answer. I have no idea what you mean by "treat it like a block".

Comment: I was always taught blocks could contain inline elements but inline elements should not contain blocks. Technology is no place to get technical eh? I jest. Thanks for your time, it cleared things up.

Comment: *I was always taught blocks could contain inline elements but inline elements should not contain blocks.* — That's a generalisation. There were plenty of exceptions in the days of HTML 4 (e.g. `P` is part of `%block;` in the HTML 4 DTD but cannot contain other `%block;` elements), there are more exceptions today.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean css display property:
    display: list-item;

Comment: What I'm asking has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
There are several types of display property. div are displayed as block as default, span - inline, li - list-item.

Answer (score -2):

```
<li> tag defines a list item.
The <li> tag is used in ordered lists <ol> or unordered lists <ul>.
```

Example.

unordered:

```
<ul>
  <li>paper</li>
  <li>pen</li>
  <li>sheet</li>
</ul>
```

ordered:

```
<ol>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

its result is as shown below

- paper
- pen
- sheet

1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Milk